# Rails: Cast string field to integer in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In a `postgres` database I have a string field `code` in `orders` table. The field contains values like 'COA-38-A', 'EFILLDIRT' and 'HE60LS-A'. There is a form on UI to filter orders based on `code` and only integer values are allowed in the field.

The query should filter the orders by integer values in the `code` field i.e if 30 is entered, the query should return orders with code 'COA-38-A' and 'HE60LS-A' because the query contains `>=`

I tried adding `::integer` in the query:

```
Order.where('code::integer >= ?', params[:code])
```

but got the following error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer
```

Is there any way to filter by only integer values?

Comment: is `COA-3A-8 ` >= 30?..

Comment: Want to pick 38 form COA-38-A and then 38 >= 30

Comment: I get that - what will you pick from COA-3A-8?.. 3? 38? 8?

Comment: all integer values i.e 38

Comment: `regexp_replace(code, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g')` should get all digits for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this?

```
Order.where("regexp_replace(0||code, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g')::integer >= ?", params[:code].to_i)
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Is it required to do  `#to_s` on `params[:code]` ?

Comment: awful answer - I don't work with rails - I just know how to do it in postgres. And thus Idont know if it should be `params[:code].to_s` or `params[:code]` - I used code from OP, but the answer was edited to be with `#to_s` If to_s stands for `to string`, I dont think it is needed at all

Comment: Yes `#to_s` is "to string".  It's an excellent answer because it solves the OP's problem and you did a creditable job on the syntax.  I would suggest `params[:code].to_i` since in fact the parameter will come in as a string and needs to be substituted as an integer.

Comment: Got this after trying: `PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""`

Comment: @Arif modified to have leading 0, so empty string would become 0